# Understanding the Boost MultiArray parameters

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-multi-array

This is from the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_example) and compiles without problems.

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

int main () {
    // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
    typedef boost::multi_array<double,3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

**My question is: What is the second template parameter?** It's not clear to me from the documentation. This code will only compile if it is set to `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's how many dimensions you need.

```
boost::extents[3][4][2] // we use 3 dimensions
```

So if you change this number, you'll have to change this line to.

Answer (score 1):

It is the 'Numeric Dimension' --- i.e. the number of dimensions of your array: three because you have three subscripts on your `boost::extents`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of dimension of the array:

you have change accordingly the ctor call :

```
array_type A(boost::extents[3][4]);
```